# How to open or download a raw pdf file coming from service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular13

I am having a challenge parsing a raw pdf file from frontend. The structure of the raw pdf file looks like this

```
%PDF-1.3 %���� 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R /PageMode /UseThumbs>>endobj2obj<</Type /Pages/Kids [ 4 0 R ]/Count 1
```

I tried using `ng2-pdf-viewer` and `pdfjs-dist` but it seems like it only takes the location of the file and not the raw file as in binary like the example above.

I've attempted this using Angular, I'd appreciate any form of help.
here's my code snippet.

```html
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfString" [show-all]="true"></pdf-viewer>
```

```
pdfString: string = '%PDF-1.7\n%�І�\n1 0 obj\n<</SubFilter/adbe.pkcs7.'
```

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer#src) you should be able to pass an object to `src` that contains the data. Could you try and see if `[src]="{ data: pdfString }"` works?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L130-L222), if your PDF file is stored as a **BASE64-encoded** string, you could use

`pdfSrc = atob(pdfString)` first to convert it to a binary string.

In the other way, you can use `pdfSrc = btoa(pdfString)` if your pdf is stored a s a simple string.

Then simply use `<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" [show-all]="true"></pdf-viewer>`